# event.pageX not working in Firefox, but does in Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-handling, html5-canvas, dom-events

I am having what I thought was a simple problem, but after about a week of searching for the solution I can't seem to find the reason behind it.

Basically I am calling the function below every time the mouse is clicked, and it works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox the `alert("This is not called")` never gets called.

I know the problem is in the two lines of code:

```
x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
```

but can't seem to find whats wrong. [Mozillas site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageX) says that `event.pageX` is a legitimate command to call,
and as well the [`canvas.offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetLeft).

But the function still isn't getting called. I have tried defining the variables in the function rather than globally, and that doesn't work, and have tried a few other alternatives out, including a jQuery event handler, but I want to try to stay away from jQuery if at all possible, mostly because I want to understand what's going on here, not just find something to patch over it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

also, the site in question is http://cabbibo.com.

EDIT:
If it helps at all, the rest of the Javascript in Firefox is running very slowly, which leads me to believe it could be a problem somewhere else in the code, for example when the side navigation is opening, each time the function for the animation is called, it takes much longer then it should.

```
function q(event){  
    if(hasBeenCalled==0){       
        event = event || window.event;
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

        x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

        alert("This Is Not Called");

        Changer2();
        stopDraw();
        moveToCenter();

        t = setInterval(rotateDrawRec, 1);
    }else{}
}
```

Comment: You have a typo
`event = event || window.event`... `;` missing

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I was posting it, the actual code has it there, Ill fix it in the question though. Thanks!

Comment: @micadelli - `;` is not required in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this:

```
<canvas id="canvas" onclick="q()"  width="1000" height="900"></canvas>

function q(event){  
    if(hasBeenCalled==0){       
        event = event || window.event;
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

        x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

        alert("This Is Not Called");

        Changer2();
        stopDraw();
        moveToCenter();

        t = setInterval(rotateDrawRec, 1);
    }else{}
}
```

Try this:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="900"></canvas>

var canvasElem = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvasElem.addEventListener("click", q, false);

function q(event){  
    if(hasBeenCalled==0){       
        event = event || window.event;

        x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        alert("This Is Not Called");

        Changer2();
        stopDraw();
        moveToCenter();

        t = setInterval(rotateDrawRec, 1);
    }else{}
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5Xs2S/3/

Comment: I am trying to get this to work, but it seems as though when I remove the var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); from the q() function, it no longer will read the click funtion, even when I add the new event Listener.

Comment: @IsaacCohen I'm not sure I follow you... there is no `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')` inside the q() function in my JSFiddle example... If you check the JSFIddle in FireFox and try each canvas, you'll see that onclick doesn't work but listener does

Comment: sorry, what I was trying to say is that the var canvas in the first piece of code, when removed, makes everything else in the script wonky, so I added it in addition to the var canvasElem, and now the rest of the program is fine, but the alert is still not called. I think it could be a problem with my placement of the               var canvasElem = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvasElem.addEventListener("click", q, false);  which I just put at the beginning of the javascript file that contains the rest of the code in question, should I be putting it in the actual html file?

Comment: I'm sorry If I'm being super convoluted, you have been super helpful this far!   I changed the position fo the two canvasElem code to the intialization function I am using with window.onload. Now the click is working (that is if I put the alert before the x and y lines, it will show) but now if I move it after those two lines, it won't work, even in chrome.

Comment: @IsaacCohen double check that your q() function is same as above, ie. use `x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft` if you want to get currently clicked element's offset values... It would really help if you show your current code in JSFiddle

Comment: That Last one did it! I was still using canvas.offsetLeft! Thank you so so so so much. I cant even begin to express how much trouble this was giving me!

Comment: Also, with JSFiddle, there is no way to link to to files on my own computert right? I would have to host them somewhere and link via url?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't figure out how to accept something as an answer, luckily there is a stack overflow on how to accept answers!

Answer (score 1):

Your site (http://cabbibo.com/) throws an "canvas3 is null" error on line 61:

```
var ctx3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");
```

This error halts the execution of the entire script, so understandably the alert in `q()` does not get called either.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Didn't solve my firefox problem, but was a  rogue piece of code that I was actually searching for for a long time!