# Event-Handling Crossbrowser Issue, mousedown window.event.clientY

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, dom, event-handling

So I am having an issue  with my event handling in a script I am writing. The entire thing is working fine in chrome, and in safari even though it runs VERY slowly, it still works. In Firefox one of the events is not working at all.

Basically, on page load I am creating a bunch of event listeners:

```
canvasElem.addEventListener("mousedown",down,false);
canvasElem.addEventListener("mouseup",up,false);
canvasElem.addEventListener("mousemove",move,false);
```

These event listeners work, of that much I am sure, but one of the event listeners (that calls the down function) stops running part way through because of these two lines of code:

```
dXImgSpin=(centerXImgSpin-expansionOffsetXImgSpin)-(window.event.clientX);
dYImgSpin=(centerYImgSpin-expansionOffsetYImgSpin)-(window.event.clientY);
```

Now I understand (kind of understand, I am new to programming so it is still a bit over my head) That this won't work in firefox because I am using the IE DOM model rather then the W3C model, but in another part of the program that I was having issues with, /* [event.pageX not working in firefox, but does in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971738/event-pagex-not-working-in-firefox-but-does-in-chrome) */ I fixed it by adding changing the way the event was handled(aka adding a canvasEleem.addEventListener), and then adding a line of code

```
event = event || window.event;
```

and changing the window.event.clientX to just event.clientX. However, when I try to do this in this different function, the above line of code won't even run.

Anything helps, and I am sorry if this question is not well phrased, But I have pretty much hit a wall in my current understanding of javascript, and can't understand how to get past it. If there is any more information that is required, don't hesitate to let me know!

Isaac

The full flow of code for when down is pressed:

```
canvasElem.addEventListener("mousedown",down,false);

function down(){

mouseDown=1;

getNewAngle();

angleMomentumImgSpin=.005;

}
```

The getNewAngle() function is the problem:

```
function getNewAngle(){

    dX2ImgSpin=dX1ImgSpin;
    dY2ImgSpin=dY1ImgSpin;
    dX1ImgSpin=dXImgSpin;
    dY1ImgSpin=dYImgSpin;



    //THESE ARE THE PART THAT ARE CAUSING THE PROBLEM
    dXImgSpin=(centerXImgSpin-expansionOffsetXImgSpin)-(window.event.clientX);
    dYImgSpin=(centerYImgSpin-expansionOffsetYImgSpin)-(window.event.clientY);


    //This if statement is to avoid the drawing from flipping when the mouse crosses the halfwaypoint
    if (dXImgSpin>0){
    angleImgSpin=(Math.atan((dYImgSpin/dXImgSpin))-angleStartImgSpin);
    }else{angleImgSpin=(Math.atan((dYImgSpin/dXImgSpin))-angleStartImgSpin+(Math.PI))}
    //alert(angle);

}
```

Comment: Think I figured it out:

the down and get new angle functions were based on an event, adding getNewAngle(event) and then 

    event = event || window.event;
and changing window.event.clientX to event.clientX seemed to do it!

Hopefully this is actually the right answer, and not some silly fix that doesn't actually create a solution, just hides the problem...